# C# how can I use #if to have different compile result for debug and release?

Tags: c#

In C++ we can use #ifdef to eliminate some debug statements when we release. C# is different from C++ in preprocessor. Can I still get the same result useing C# #if. We want to eliminate ALL debug statements by change one place and we have several different types of debug statements. Can have one file which contains ALL our #ifdef flags to turn on or turn off those debug statements? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The according the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt3yck0x.aspx)

> The scope of a symbol created by using #define  is the file in which it was defined.

So you can't have a file that defines several other defines that are used throughout your program.  The easiest way to do this would be to have different configurations on your project file and specifying the list of defines for each configuration on the command line to the compiler.

**Update:**
You can set your project defines in Visual Studio by right-clicking on your project and selecting **Properties**.  Then select the **Build** tab.  Under general you can specify the defines to be sent to the compiler under "Conditional compilation symbols".  You can define different project settings using the Configuration Manager (Build->Configuration Manager)

**Update 2:**
When the "Conditional compilation symbols" are specified, Visual Studio emits a `/define` on the command line for the compiler (csc.exe for C#), you can see this by examining the output window when building your project.  From the [MSDN docs for csc.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0feaad6z.aspx)

> The /define option has the same effect
>   as using a #define  preprocessor
>   directive except that the compiler
>   option is in effect for all files in
>   the project. A symbol remains defined
>   in a source file until an #undef 
>   directive in the source file removes
>   the definition. When you use the
>   /define option, an #undef directive in
>   one file has no effect on other source
>   code files in the project.
>
> You can use symbols created by this
>   option with #if, #else, #elif, and
>   #endif to compile source files conditionally.

Comment: You can define compile constants in the project files, per configuration.  DEBUG is defined by default.

Comment: can you tell me more details about your easiest way?

Comment: the conditional compilation symbols set in that way works for ALL files of that project?

Answer (score 19):

You can wrap code in:

```
#if DEBUG

// debug only code

#endif
```

However, I don't recommend this.  It's often a better alternative to just make a method and flag it with the `[Conditional("DEBUG")]` attribute.  See [Conditional on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4xssyw96.aspx) for more details.  This allows you to make debug only methods:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
public void DebugPrint(string output) { // ... 
}
```

Then, you can call this normally:

```
DebugPrint("Some message"); // This will be completely eliminated in release mode
```

Comment: if we use conditional attribute to define the DebugPrint method in Class A. Then we call it in Class B, Class C and ..... If that condition is false at compile time, ALL statements call that method will not be compiled (eliminated)?

Comment: Yes.  The entire method - and all of the points that call it, are automatically removed from the final IL.  It's a more maintainable alternative than using #if DEBUG in many cases.

Answer (score 4):

Use something like:

```
#if DEBUG

System.Console.WriteLine("This is debug line");

#endif
```