# How to change uritemplate according to the staging enviornment in Restfull wcf service

Tags: wcf

I am having following operation contract for my non-prod environment

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "members/Empdata")]
```

but I need to change this `uritemplate` for my prod environment like below

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "members/Empdata/Search")]
```

I tried so many things none of them work out

I tried to put a key into `web.config` but the interface doesn't allow to accept anything from config.

Comment: It is easier and preferred to have a staging environment that is the same / uses the same urls.

Comment: you can't change the uritemplate because that string needs to be a constant / known at compile time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827799/using-variables-within-attributes-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only handle this at compile time, not at runtime.

I would really expect a Staging and Production environment does allow for the same url structure with respect to a common root. They are part of the contract.

If you really want to fix this in code then you could use compiler directives and have the two variants in the code governed by providing the correct compile parameters.

```csharp
[OperationContract]
#if STAGING
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", 
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
           BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, 
           UriTemplate = "members/Empdata")]
#endif
#if PRODUCTION
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", 
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
           BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, 
           UriTemplate = "members/Empdata/Search")]
#endif
public string Search(string data)
```

Now you need to make sure you have build configurations for Staging and Production and set the correct Conditional compilation symbols for each.

See also: [C# how can I use #if to have different compile result for debug and release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232094/c-sharp-how-can-i-use-if-to-have-different-compile-result-for-debug-and-release)

Comment: getting duplicate webinvoke method

Comment: Don't include STAGING and PRODUCTION at the same time for the same build config. Pick one and only one.